# How to RESET the output data on a screen, and not merely clear the screen

Tags: reset

A couple of days ago, on a different thread, I asked the question as to how I can represent an output such as "#Grades As : 5" into the output "#Grade As : AAAAA". In other words, I wanted to represent the  quantity 5 A's as a string of A's repeated five times. The user Sam Jones very helpfully pointed out to me that I should use a "for" loop:

```
                  String gradeLetterA = "A";
                  for (int i=0; i<tempAs; i++) 
                  longStringA += gradeLetterA;
```

Now, let me show you my actionPerformed method :

```
        if (e.getSource() == clearScreen) {

        checkAndRecordData();

        Graphics g = chartPanel.getGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(20,20,410,52);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(20,20,410,52);
        g.setColor( Color.black );
        g.drawString( "", chartLeftXA, chartTopYA );



        if (e.getSource() == displayLongString) {

        Graphics g = chartPanel.getGraphics(); 

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(20,20,410,52);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(20,20,410,52);
        g.setColor( Color.black );
        g.drawString( "Grade As: " + longStringA, 100, 50 );
```

My question to you good folks is this : When I click on a JButton button to refresh the display of "AAAAA", the screen goes blank, as it's supposed to. However, when I then choose to input the value of (for example) 6 A's, the display does NOT give me 6 letter A's, but ELEVEN letter A's, ie. AAAAAAAAAAA. In other words, my RESET (or refresh) JButton only clears the screen, but it does NOT erase the previous value. Instead, it ADDS the previous value to the current value and I get the WRONG number of A's when I click the button a second time. Can someone please tell me what line of code I should add to the actionPerformed method to make it right? Or does this line have to go into the create GUI method? I'm completely lost. Any help would be gratefully welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't seem to be in your actionPerformed. It's in the first section of code. You said yourself it doesn't erase the previous value. I think you aren't clearing longStringA

```
longStringA = "";
String gradeLetterA = "A";
for (int i=0; i<tempAs; i++)  {
    longStringA += gradeLetterA;
}
```

You are always writing to the same location on screen: (100, 50). If the problem was not erasing the previous value, then creating 5 As and then 6 As should draw AAAAAA, with the first 5 As perhaps being a little bit more bold than the last one (because AAAAAA was drawn on top of AAAAA).

Comment: @ Millie Smith: Oh, I see. Much appreciated !

Comment: @ Millie Smith : Oh, I see. Much appreciated !

Comment: @ Millie Smith, yes, works just fine. Wasted so much time trying to figure out fancy solutions which didn't work. Simplicity is always the best.